# Multiple model in a view(mvc)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

I have MVC project that I connected  to an existing Database in SQL Server.I want to use more than one model in a view to connecting to more than one table and get fields from user or display them to user.
How can I do it?

I tried to using `ViewModel` but I cant pass `IEnumerable` list to model

first model:

```
public partial class Amniyat
{
    public int AmniyatID { get; set; }
    public string NamKarbar { get; set; }
    public string Ramz { get; set; }
    public string KalameBazyabi { get; set; }
    public int NoeKarbarID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TarikhIjad { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime TarikhEtebar { get; set; }
    public bool VaziyatKarbar { get; set; }
    public string Nam { get; set; }
    public string Famili { get; set; }
    public string Tozihat { get; set; }

}
```

second model:

```
public partial class NoeKarbar
{
    public int NoeKarbarID { get; set; }
    public string NoeKarbar1 { get; set; }
    public string NoeDastresi { get; set; }
    public string Tozihat { get; set; }            
}
```

my ViewModel:

```
public class AmniyatNoeKarbar
{
  public  IEnumerable<Amniyat> AMN { get; set; }
  public  IEnumerable<NoeKarbar> NK { get; set; }
}
```

controller that i want to use viewmodel in this:

```
 private HousingAgencyEntities db = new HousingAgencyEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        NoeKarbar nk = db.NoeKarbars.Find(1);
        Amniyat amn = db.Amniyats.Find(1);

      AmniyatNoeKarbar mymodel = new AmniyatNoeKarbar { AMN = amn, NK = nk };
        return View(mymodel);
    }
```

but I  have error in line AMN=amn,NK=nk

Answer (score 1):

Does your .Find() method return IEnumerable<>? I have seen a lot of Find(int) methods which return only the base object which would fail to convert into your IEnumerable<>.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<NoeKarbar> nk = new IEnumerable<NoeKarbar>.add(db.NoeKarbars.Find(1));
    IEnumerable<Amniyat> amn = new IEnumerable<Amniyat>().add(db.Amniyats.Find(1));

   AmniyatNoeKarbar mymodel = new AmniyatNoeKarbar { AMN = amn, NK = nk };
    return View(mymodel);
}
```